# Binding property model value to array in v-for when checked box Check/Uncheck

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am implementing the `v-for` as follows:

```
<div id="app">
      <p> SeletedId's {{ selectedIds }}</p>
      <div v-for="(pay, index) in PaymentType">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedIds" :value="pay.Id"/>     {{pay.Text}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Initially `selectedIds` is empty array.

Is there any way in Vue to push the Id's to the `Id` which is inside the selectedIds as array of object.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    PaymentType:[
      {Id: 1, Text:"Cash"},
      {Id: 2, Text:"Check"},
      {Id: 3, Text:"Paypal"}
   ],
   selectedIds:[]
  }
})
```

I wanted to change my selectedIds from an array of numbers to array of object, like `selectedIds:[{selectedId:0}]` and so on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, right now `selectedIds` is an array of numbers, but you want it an array of objects. In that case, change the `:value` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedIds" :value="pay.Id"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedIds" :value="pay"/>
```

This way you will get:

```
selectedId : [{Id: 1, Text: "Cash"}, {Id: 2, Text: "Check"}]
```

## Just the `Id`

On the other hand, if you just want the `Id` property's value, to get something like:

```
selectedId: [{selectedId: 1}, {selectedId: 2}]
```

You can use an object in the `:value` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedIds" :value="{selectedId: pay.Id}"/>
```

Comment: I wanted to use that making selectedIds as the array of objects. I may havIe some other field inside selectedIds like `selectedIds:[{Id:0, Remarks: ''}]`

Comment: Oh, I see, you actually want the other way around of what I said, right?

Comment: Yes. Currently i have `selectedIds:[1]` and i want to implement like this `selectedIds:[{Id:1}]`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. you got confused with Id on both array. Because i mention `Id` on selectedIds. Actually i wanted only Ids. not the text and actually my `selectedIds` is `selectedIds:[{selectedId:0,Remarks:''}]`

Comment: Great! Works perfectly like what i wanted.

Comment: Is it possible that i can add the value from text box to the same array objects into another field?

Comment: May be I should not ask this question here?

Comment: It is possible, but probably not with just regular attribute binding. But you would have to show the whole case. About asking here, you could, but it is probably better if you ask another question entirely (don't worry that is not frowned upon, on the contrary) because in a new question you would have more space to explain the problem, and also could get help from others, not just me.